# How to retrieve posts where the organization is mentioned

Tags: linkedin-api

Is it possible to retrieve posts where an organization is mentioned through the LinkedIn API?

I found some information in the API documentation (link below) that indicates that it is possible, but there is no information on which endpoint should be used or available details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/social-access-control#retrieving-posts-with-organizational-mentions

Comment: Any luck? I'm investigating this very question at the moment, will let you know once I figure something out!

Comment: I was able to speak with the API support and they told me that it is not yet possible to collect this type of data, but that they are working to make this option available.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no LinkedIn API for this.  It does not have feature to retrieve posts based on keyword.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).